# Installed parametirized plugin but it doesn't show up on the dashboard after restart

Tags: jenkins

Installed parameterised jenkins plugin:

*parameterized-trigger.hpi       2023-06-28 20:37  129K*

I can see it in my .jenkins/plugins folder.

After restarting jenkins, I do not see it on the Jenkins dashboard

Screenshots as proofs:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not supposed to be visible on the left side of the dashboard after installation.
You need to go to:

```
 "your pipeline project" > Configure > This project is parameterised
```

Only then will it appear on the left side as following:

```
 Build with parameters
```

The plugin name isL *parameterized-trigger.hpi* and should be installed via jenkins UI or download the file manually and put it in `.jenkins/plugins`